# How to access n-D matrix with n index vectors?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, matrix-indexing

I have a matrix

```
A = repmat(1:7,7,1);
```

I have index vectors

```
idx1 = [1 3 5];
idx2 = [1 3 5];
```

I want to access A at the 2d coordinates denoted by idx1(i),idx2(i).

When I do

```
A(idx1,idx2) = 0;
```

I get for each element in idx 1, all the elements in idx2 as well.
I want only the corresponding elements to be assigned the zero value.

Again: I get

```
A = 
0 2 0 4 0 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 2 0 4 0 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 2 0 4 0 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

but I want

```
A = 
0 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 0 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 0 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

How to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: For clarification, should the first row of your desired output be `0 2 1 4 1 6 7` or `0 2 3 4 5 6 7`?

Comment: sorry. editted now.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks for asking OP to clarify. I guess I can undelete my answer now.

Comment: @edwinksl you're welcome, I deleted mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use [**`sub2ind`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to generate the linear indices needed to index into `A`:

```
linear_ind = sub2ind(size(A),idx1,idx2);
A(linear_ind) = 0;
```